# TRR_TO_NUMBER is not defined in STRING_FUNCTION Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a problem with my function ;( What function should do ? It should check if the string is a string or if it's number. So I have created a UDF

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tring_function(s string)
    RETURNS string
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS 
    $$
    if(isNan(S)) {
    return 'not a number';
    } else {
    return S ;
    }
    $$
    ;
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong ;(

The error message :

> "JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: isNan is not defined in STRING_FUNCTION at ' if(isNan(S)) {' position 4 stackstrace: STRING_FUNCTION line: 2
> "

Answer (score 1):

The function is `isNaN` and not `isNan`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION string_function(s string)
    RETURNS string
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS 
    $$
    if(isNaN(S)) {
    return 'not a number';
    } else {
    return S ;
    }
    $$
    ;
```

Output:

[image]

Another way is usage of [TRY_TO_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_decimal.html) which is built-in.